# Weird behavior in Firefox with outlines and pseudo-elements

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-element

Firefox behaves differently than Chrome and Safari (I haven't tested others browsers) when you combine outline and pseudo-elements.
Is there a way to fix it or is this a bug?

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  outline: 2px solid #00f;
}
.main:after {
  content: 'Hello';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -50px;
}
.wtf {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 90px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="wtf">
  <p>In Chrome and Safari the 'Hello' is outside of the outline.</p>
  <p>In firefox the outline is extended and the 'Hello' is inside the outline. Bug from Firefox or is there a way to fix this?</p>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/romainberger/pen/nuxlh

Edit:
Tested in Firefox 20.0, Chrome 28 and Safari 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now used to

**box shadow**

**as like this**

```
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  z-index:1;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px #00f;
}
.main:after {
  content: 'Hello';
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:2;
}

.wtf {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 90px auto;
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vmtfh)**

Comment: I haven't thought about box shadow, it works great. I was kinda worried about browser support but it just exclude IE8, so I'm gonna go with "screw IE8". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No need to use z-index.

```
.main { 
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px #00f;
}
.main:after {
  content: 'Hello';
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.wtf {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 90px auto;
}
```